# Send a SAML request by POST using saml2-js in Node

Tags: node.js, saml-2.0

I've gone through the documentation (however limited) to connect to an IDP. It's all configured and working properly except one thing. The IDP won't accept SAML Requests via GET.

Does saml2-js support HTTP POST for sending SAML requests to the IDP and if so, how is this coded? If not, is there an alternative NPM package that would work?

Currently i have:

```
        sso.sp.create_login_request_url(sso.idp,{},(err, login_url, requestId) => {
            console.log('err',err)
            console.log('login_url',login_url)
            console.log('requestId',requestId);
            response.redirect(login_url);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

An addition to jsub's answer:

The POST request to the IdP must be made by the browser, not by the server (by `needle` in jsub's case). Only the browser contains the IdP session cookie which authenticates the user with the IdP. `res` must contain an HTML page with an auto-submitting `<form>` with one `<input>` per `param`:

```js
app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
  sso.sp.create_login_request_url(sso.idp, {}, function(err, login_url, requestId) {
    var url = new URL(login_url);
    res.type("html");
    res.write(`<!DOCTYPE html><html>
      <body onload="document.querySelector('form').submit()">
        <form action="${url.protocol}//${url.host}${url.pathname}" method="post">`);
    for (const [param, value] of url.searchParams)
      res.write(`<input name="${param}" value="${value}"/>`);
    res.end(`</form></body></html>`);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to work around this as well, and my attempts have not worked but the approach is to make a separate http POST request with a client (using needle in my case) and then try to pipe the response from that into the response for the handler, e.g. something like this:

```
sso.sp.create_login_request_url(sso.idp, {}, (err, login_url, requestId) => {
  // response.redirect(login_url);
  const [url, param] = login_url.split("?")
  const postOptions = {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  }

  needle.post(Url, param, postOptions, (err, postResponse) => {
    postResponse.pipe(res) 
  });
```

However I am not having much luck, trying to dig into why the pipe does not work

EDIT: the piping seems to work when I do it in this short form

```
needle.post(url, param, postOptions).pipe(res)
```